# automating regular windows functions using c sharp

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I am trying to build a windows application that will automate a regular routine steps that I have to do for taking a backup.

The flow goes like this...

1.open a folder
2.run an exe there
3.open jumpbox server at which point we have to enter a username and password
4.create a folder
5.then open a network folder using the ip such as //ip.ip.ip.ip/folder (i do this from run)
6.copy a file from this folder to the created folder and rename it

and some other stuff like this.

I handle some of the stuff like open a folder, creating a folder and stuff like that but how to connect to a network folder and give the username and password to it when its asking from within the application.

Comment: Does it have to be in C# or VB.NET?  This would be a great job for Powershell (which can use CLR objects if you wish), or even a regular cmd.exe batch script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these things that can be controlled with a .Net application.

You can use `System.Diagnotics.Process` to launch other executables in a process.

Both `System.IO.Directory` and `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` can be used to do all sorts of folder manipulation.

As for connecting to a network drive which, I think is the actual question, you'll have to excuse my ignorance on jumpboxes. If a user on your domain has access you will need to **impersonate** that user as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249540/how-to-present-credentials-in-order-to-open-file), or if it is a seperate domain, as I suspect is the case, you can use the **API** as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials).

Comment: Thank you, as i mentioned in the mail i did know about both diagnostics and directory, but this wnet is really what i need and didnt know so far about.

Answer (score 1):

I see you run external commands, so you could use `"NET USE..."`.
Run `NET HELP USE` to see syntax...