# How to read a file on a different machine

Tags: c#, windows

I have the following information:

- remote machine name/address
- credentials for an account with administrative privileges on the remote machine
- complete path of the file I need (ex: C:\program files\application\file.txt)

My application is running on a local machine with administrative privileges as well.

How would I open/read the remote file?

Note: there is no guarantee that the file is located in a shared path.

Comment: Have you tried `\\FullyQualifiedMachineName\c$\program files\application\file.txt`?

Comment: just a suggestion if you can - you are better off - if you can map the drive ( where file is located) to local machine ( where application is running) or just shared the drive and then you can use the shared drive as folder path

Comment: accessing by path \\FQDN\c$\path doesn't work in the case that the current user's account isn't admin on the remote machine

Comment: why would I want to map the entire drive? I only need to read a file from the machine. I'm not planning on accessing anything else on the drive.

Comment: @iliaden: re. having to be an admin - right, but I thought you said you were.

Comment: I have admin rights on the current machine, and I know the credentials for the remote machine. 
I'm not sure where I need to enter those credentials to be able to access the needed path.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to run into a few problems. First, it looks like you want to pass credentials to the remote server. Take a [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/249594/192536) for passing your remote credentials when opening files directly.

Second, you can use the Admin UNC share path: `\\machinename\drive$\path\file.txt`. But this will only work if the user does not have a firewall active and only if you are passing the credentials of an admin user.

Basically, firewalls and access permissions are your main problems. It's a lot easier to get into someone else's stuff if they explicitly share it with you.