# Check user permissions

Tags: c#, file-permissions, directory-permissions

I have an Application running in a server, that takes a username and file path. The idea to check if the user can read the file (the target user **is not** the same user running the program).

So how to check read permissions for **specific user** ??

Comment: http://www.conarc.com/blog/2010/03/25/programmatically-getting-effective-directoryfile-permissions/

Comment: Don't put tags in title !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't take responsibility for this as I googled it and the answer was by James Newton-King found here- [How to present credentials in order to open file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249540/how-to-present-credentials-in-order-to-open-file)

---

You want to impersonate a user who does have the rights to access the file.

I recommend using a class like this - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx. It hides all the nasty implementation of doing impersonation.

```
using (new Impersonator("myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword"))
{
  string fileText = File.ReadAllText("c:\test.txt");
  Console.WriteLine(fileText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this Documentation, this might be useful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getattributes(v=vs.110).aspx